# Formatting USB external HDD fails with IO error

Tags: hard-disk, ext4, mkfs, proxmox

Output of lsblk:

```
root@pve:~# lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                            8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1                         8:1    0 1007K  0 part 
├─sda2                         8:2    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda3                         8:3    0  1.8T  0 part 
  ├─pve-swap                 253:0    0    8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─pve-root                 253:1    0   96G  0 lvm  /
  ├─pve-data_tmeta           253:2    0 15.8G  0 lvm  
  │ └─pve-data-tpool         253:4    0  1.7T  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-data             253:5    0  1.7T  1 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--101--disk--0 253:6    0   20G  0 lvm  
  │   ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0 253:7    0   32G  0 lvm  
  │   └─pve-vm--103--disk--0 253:8    0   20G  0 lvm  
  └─pve-data_tdata           253:3    0  1.7T  0 lvm  
    └─pve-data-tpool         253:4    0  1.7T  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-data             253:5    0  1.7T  1 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--101--disk--0 253:6    0   20G  0 lvm  
      ├─pve-vm--102--disk--0 253:7    0   32G  0 lvm  
      └─pve-vm--103--disk--0 253:8    0   20G  0 lvm  
sdb                            8:16   0  4.5T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                         8:17   0  4.5T  0 part
```

Output of mkfs.ext4:

```
root@pve:~# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
mke2fs 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Creating filesystem with 1220702976 4k blocks and 152588288 inodes
Filesystem UUID: acb840f0-2589-44da-b073-fe91e289991b
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
        102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: mkfs.ext4: Input/output error while writing out and closing file system
```

Output of dmesg:

```
[  164.597912] DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 2
[  164.597914] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: WARNING: Host System Error
[  164.597974] DMAR: [DMA Read NO_PASID] Request device [07:00.0] fault addr 0x0 [fault reason 0x06] PTE Read access is not set
[  169.780398] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[  169.780404] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: USBSTS: 0x0000000d HCHalted HSE EINT
[  169.780412] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[  169.780476] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[  169.780538] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  169.780730] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  169.796412] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 32 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 28 prio class 2
[  169.796471] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2080 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 28 prio class 2
[  169.796490] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  169.796501] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 0, lost async page write
[  169.796520] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 9765625728 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 16 prio class 0
[  169.796534] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 544 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 28 prio class 0
[  169.796592] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 2592 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 28 prio class 0
[  169.796649] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 9767539744 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 28 prio class 0
[  169.796697] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 15168 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  169.796719] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 9765624864 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 28 prio class 0
[  169.796733] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 9767540256 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 28 prio class 0
[  169.796911] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702960, lost async page write
[  169.796928] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702961, lost async page write
[  169.796937] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702962, lost async page write
[  169.796945] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702963, lost async page write
[  169.796953] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702964, lost async page write
[  169.796960] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702965, lost async page write
[  169.796970] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702966, lost async page write
[  169.796980] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702967, lost async page write
[  169.796991] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 1220702968, lost async page write
[  169.824451] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  170.116424] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  170.117181] xhci_hcd 0000:07:00.0: WARN Can't disable streams for endpoint 0x82, streams are being disabled already
```

Comment: It's dead or dying considering all the IO errors in the log. Trying a different USB cable is still a good idea.

Comment: It's not all that old. Any chance it is not a hardware issue? Any other output I should provide to help diagnose?

Comment: Portable HDDs are generally very unreliable :-( This definitely looks like a HW issue. You could provide `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb` output but these errors alone indicate it's not working properly.